# Injectivity of the exponential map of compact connected Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to learn Lie Algebra with a little knowledge of Differential Geometry. I have read that the exponential map of compact connected Lie groups is always surjective. So I am wondering about the injectivity of the exponential map for compact connected Lie groups. I think it can not be injective and the multiplication of 1-torus with 1-sphere($T^1\times S^1$) is a counter example. Is this true? If so how can I prove it in a proper way?

Comment: As Tsemo Aristide's answer shows, the easiest (non-trivial) example is the easiest counterexample, $G= S^1$, where the exponential is basically the quotient map $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is compact, then $G$ has a subgroup isomorphic to the circle, therefore the exponential is not injective.

Comment: Maybe exclude $\mathcal{G}=\{0\}, G=\{1\}$ for pedants like me.

Comment: The exponential map is *not*, in general, a local diffeomorphism.  For example, on $SU(2)$, the exponential map has conjugate locus consisting of a $2$-sphere of radius $\pi$ in $\mathfrak{su}(2)\cong \mathbb{R}^3$.  (I'm implicitly assuming $SU(2)$ is equipped with a bi-invariant metric scaled in such a way that the Riemanian exponential map coincides with the group exponential map, but this can always be done on a compact Lie group.)  It *is* diffeomophism onto its image when restricted to a small enough neighborhood of $0$.